# How can I pass the absolute path of my function load into my function predict?

Tags: python

I would like to get the path and the file name of my load function and pass it to my predict function

Every time I use the code self.load() I also need to call its arguments which is the path and the filename. How do I get the path and the filename that is inside my load function.

[This is the screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM0T9.jpg)

I try to run the function load inside my predict function but i need the parameters [path] and [filename]

```
def load(self, path, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
        self.ids.image.source = filename[0]
    self.dismiss_popup()
    pathh = (os.path.join(path,filename[0]))
    return os.path.join(path,filename[0])
def predict(self):
    #need to pass the path and filename here
```

Comment: do you know how to return values?

Comment: yes sir.. but i am still a newbie on python..

Comment: you should see [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: sorry i'll edit my question and post my code

Comment: You can give more generic title like "How to pass parameters of a function to another?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use class attributes**

If you put both functions inside a class (making them methods), you can set `path` and `filename` as class attributes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = ''
        self.filename = ''

    def load(self, path, filename):
        self.path = path
        self.filename = filename

    def predict(self):
        print(self.path)
        print(self.filename)

foo_instance = Foo()
foo_instance.load('/test/path', 'a_file.txt')
foo_instance.predict()
```

Expected result:

```
>> '/test/path'
>> 'a_file.txt'
```

**Use global variables**

If you don't want to use a class, you can use the `global` keyword to enable you to modify a variable is scoped higher than the function.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

path_outer_scope = ''
filename_outer_scope = ''

def load(self, path, filename):
    global path_outer_scope
    global filename_outer_scope
    path_outer_scope = path
    filename_outer_scope = filename

def predict(self):
    print(path_outer_scope)
    print(filename_outer_scope)

load('/test/path', 'a_file.txt')
predict()
```

Expected result:

```
>> '/test/path'
>> 'a_file.txt'
```

If you did not use the `global` keyword, I would expect to see

```
>> ''
>> ''
```

**Which should I use?**

Placing the functions inside a class is 'cleaner code' because the variables are still restricted to that class, and are not available to functions that don't need them. They are also namespaced within the class so there is less chance of a name collision.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare empty strings on the top of your functions and when `load()` is called assign the values:

```
pth = ""
fname = ""


def load(self, path, filename):
    pth = path
    fname = filename
    # your code here

def predict(self):
    # use pth and fname here
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir.. but when i use pth and fname on my predict function it have an error or unresolved reference

Comment: I didn't get the problem. Where do u use this code(django sth.)?